# Multiple elevation labels on contours

Tags: qgis, labeling

[image: Labels Dialogue box]
[image: Screen Snip]
[image: Attribute Table]

I extracted contours from a DTM generated by **Pix4dSurvey** from a drone mapping mission. However, when I try to label the contours in QGIS with the derived elevations, some of them have multiple labels *(of different elevation values)*. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please share a bit more about your data. How did you set up Labels ? What does the Attribute Table look like in your Contour layer. From what you show, one possible reason would be to have multiple contour lines with the same shapes but different laltitudes / labels

Comment: Thank you, @Kasper in fact, what you said makes sense. If that is the case, should I say there was a problem with the DTM I used or the process itself, right?

Comment: Most probably the process itself. You can use QGIS to generate the contour lines from your DTM if you wish.